# How to Get the SelectedValue of Combox inside an DataGridTemplateColumn in wpf Datagrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, combobox, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have am DataGridTemplate Column with an Combox inside it.I want to get the selected value of an combox in an particular row when they cllick on the save button oputside the DataGrid.

Comment: The best method would be to keep track of the selected value as it happens.  The user would have to click on selected row and column to store a value.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a very good approach since you cannot directly access rows or the controls that visualize them from the selection. I'd suggest you use events to signal that changes should be committed or something similar to that.